# Combining Jquery and Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a relatively novice question. I have the following jQuery function:

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'testapi.php',       
      data: "query="+queryType,
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(data) 
      {
        var id = data[0];
        $('#'+divID).html(id); 
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm looking to name and parameterize the function so that I can call it repeatedly (with the parameters queryType and divID which are already included in the code). I've tried unsuccessfully multiple times. Would anyone have any insight?

Comment: Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick it in a function

```
function doAjax(queryType, divID) {
    return $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'testapi.php',       
        data: {query : queryType},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        var id = data[0];
        $('#'+divID).html(id);
    });
}
```

and use it

```
$(function() {
    element.on('click', function() {
        var id = this.id
        doAjax('get_content', id);
    }); 
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    element.on('click', function() {
        var id = this.id
        doAjax('get_content', id).done(function(data) {
              // do something more with the returned data
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a simple function to wrap the ajax call give this a try. Place this function above the document ready code.

```
function callAjax(queryType, divID) {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'testapi.php',       
        data: "query="+queryType,
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) {
            var id = data[0];
            $('#'+divID).html(id); 
        }
    });
}
```

To call the function do this:

```
callAjax('YourQueryHere', 'YourDivIdHere');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doThis(queryType, divID)
{
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'testapi.php',       
      data: "query="+queryType,
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(data) 
      {
        var id = data[0];
        $('#'+divID).html(id); 
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(queryType, divID) 
{
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'testapi.php',       
    data: "query="+queryType,
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) 
      {
        var id = data[0];
        $('#'+divID).html(id); 
      }
  });
}
```

and to call it simply use

```
myFunction("someQueryType", "myDiv");
```